# Need help understanding a decider

Tags: computability, finite-automata

currently working through slides and I've noticed this which I believe to be an error.

Shouldn't the two DFA's be swapped around, so that the one that reaches the accept state is with L(M)=nothing is the accept state?
If not could you explain why?

[image: See Image here]

Comment: Could you link to the source of those slides, please? Other people's content needs to be acknowledged. Thanks.

Comment: These are links to my lecturers slides at uni but I'm 99% certain she copied them from somewhere so I wouldn't be able to tell you the source, as I don't know it.

Comment: Then cite your lecturer; she can answer for any plagiarism she committed. Anyway, posts that consist mostly of images are bad: please transcribe the relevant parts so they can be searched, copy-pasted, ...

Answer (score 2):

What these slides are describing is an algorithm (Turing Machine), which looks at a DFA and asks "does this DFA accept the empty language?"

So the diagrams in the slides are correct. If there is no path to an accepting state, then the answer is "yes, this DFA accepts the empty language," and our algorithm should output "true."

You would reverse the diagrams if you were writing an algorithm which was "test whether there exists some string that the given DFA accepts".

Comment: But surely if the DFA doesn't reach an accept state then it's not accepted? Sorry I'm confused by your answer :(

Comment: We are never running the DFA. We are just giving the DFA description as input to a Turing Machine (algorithm), which looks at that DFA's properties.

Comment: I think my confusion is where it says accepts empty language, does this mean that it accepts no languages?

Comment: That means that the DFA in question accepts no words. But that's the key here. If the DFA accepts no words, then the Turing Machine accepts the DFA. If there's some word the DFA accepts, then the TM rejects the DFA.